# Enabling HTTPS tag

Tags: support, tags

I wish I could use the `HTTPS` tag for a question related to enabling `SSL` but I had this warning which didn't let me create it.

[image: error message]

Could it be fixed? I think it is worth it.

Answer (score 4):

I think that warning is being triggered to avoid having many tags present in both singular and plural forms, even though the "s" on the end is not for that purpose, in this instance.

I thought that we would need SE staff/developers to implement it, as an exception, and that it would be better to just use the existing [ssl](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssl) tag along with [http](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/http), when both are important.

However, from a test by another moderator, it looks like we moderators actually can create a tag like this one without seeing that warning.  Consequently, I think that if someone adds an answer proposing we exercise that functionality, and if there appears to be consensus that this tag is needed, then I or another moderator can proceed to create it with negligible effort.